# What is a better lens for Mirrorless camera? EF-M 55-200 mm vs EF-S 55-250 mm with adapter

Tags: lens, canon

I just ordered the EF-M 55-200 mm. I was looking only for lens directly for M, but after I made the order I also checked the EF-S / EF lenses and I found that they are probably better like 55-250 mm, and maybe there will be even some 18-200mm or similar and price is similar as my lens.

Did I made mistake by buying my lense, is it better some other EF(S) lens + adapter?

Comment: Hi! Please provide some more information. What exactly do you mean by "better"?

Comment: "Better" in what way? Longer focal length range? Wider focal length ratio? Maximum aperture? Image quality at any particular focal length and aperture setting? Usability on the EOS-M platform? Price? Compact size? Something else?